# Hightlight all file tabs with code modifications in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse, 'Quick Diff' from preferences can be used to highlight the Changes, Additions and Deletions in the 'Overview ruler' in editor.

Also, colors for files in 'Project Explorer' can be changed from 'Colors and Fonts' window.

But is there a config or **plugin to highlight opened files in tabs above the editor**, similar to that of Netbeans as shown below?

[image]

Comment: There should already be an asterisk at the start of the tab label on any modified editor, bubbling them to the top of the editor list (Ctrl/CMD+E).

Comment: Unsaved files display asterisk.
Is there a way to display an asterisk or any symbol for **saved but uncommitted** file?